# How to print a type of getter

Tags: java, reflection, getter

I have code like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    printGettersSetters(PodmiotSzukajQueryFormSet.class);
}

public static void printGettersSetters(Class aClass) {
    Method[] methods = aClass.getMethods();

    for (Method method: methods) {
        if (isGetter(method)) {
            System.out.println("getter: " + method);    
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isGetter(Method method) {
    if (!method.getName().startsWith("getSomething")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 0) return false;
    if (void.class.equals(method.getReturnType())) return false;
    return true;
}
```

output:

> getter: public package.package.Class
>   package.package.Class.getSomething()

How can I get a type of that getter, in this example: "Class" but in other examples "String" , "int" etc.

--edit
it is possible with
.getModifiers() but it returns int. How can I return String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what you are looking for the the method `getReturnType()` of the object `java.lang.reflect.Method`

> public Class getReturnType()
>
> Returns a Class object that represents the formal return type of the
>   method represented by this Method object.
>
> Returns:the return type for
>   the method this object represents

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your for loop:

```
for (Method method : methods) {
  if (isGetter(method)) {
    String type = String.valueOf(method.getReturnType());
    System.out.println("getter: " + method + ". Return type: " + type);
  }
}
```

Comment: String type = String.valueOf(method.getReturnType());